# Unable to update a form using curl post

Tags: php, bash, curl, post

I am trying to use a script to interact with the a website however whenever i send my curl post request, nothing is returned.

```
curl -X POST --proxy 1.1.1.1:9443 \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d d="google.com" -d n="8.8.8.8" \
-d q="A" http://http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php
```